# Is there a script that normalizes a poorly-created database table?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have my database structured like this: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u24KU.png) but I would like it in this format: [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUqve.png). Is there some PostgreSQL script available that basically converts these formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's small, then you can write this query:

```
select serial_number, number1 from bad_table
union all
select serial_number, number2 from bad_table
union all
select serial_number, number3 from bad_table
;
```

If you do not want empty values copied, then add a `not null` restriction:

```
select serial_number, number1 from bad_table where number1 is not null
union all
select serial_number, number2 from bad_table where number2 is not null
union all
select serial_number, number3 from bad_table where number3 is not null
;
```

If it's bigger than this, then you can construct this query from `information_schema.columns`.

```
with queries as (
  select concat('select serial_number, ',
                column_name,
                ' from bad_table where ',
                column_name,
                ' is not null') as query
    from information_schema.columns
   where table_name = 'bad_table'
     and column_name like 'number%'
), asarray as (
  select array_agg(query) as qs
    from queries
)
select array_to_string(qs, ' union all ')
  from asarray;
```

This might need some simplification, but it is a start:

```
with tname as (                                                                                                                                                                                                               select 'bad_table' as t                                                                                                                                                                                                              ), stemmed_columns as (
  select column_name::text as column_name, 
         regexp_replace(column_name, '\d+$', '') as rootname, 
         regexp_replace(column_name, '^\D+', '') as ind
    from information_schema.columns 
   cross join tname 
   where table_name = tname.t
), col_arrays as (
  select array_to_string(
           array_agg(column_name) 
             filter (where ind = ''),
           ', '
         ) as leadcols,
         array_agg(column_name order by column_name)
           filter (where ind != '')
         as icols,
         array_agg(distinct rootname order by rootname) 
           filter (where ind != '')
          as stems 
    from stemmed_columns
), index_limits as (
  select distinct ind::int as indint
    from stemmed_columns
   where ind != ''
), blowout as (
  select l.indint, 
         array_agg(
           case 
             when (s.stem||l.indint::text) = any(a.icols) then s.stem||l.indint::text
             else 'null' 
           end || ' as '|| s.stem order by s.stem) as srcname,
         array_agg(
           case 
             when (s.stem||l.indint::text) = any(a.icols) then s.stem||l.indint::text
             else 'null' 
           end order by s.stem) as srcnameonly
    from index_limits l
   cross join col_arrays a
   cross join (select unnest(stems) as stem from col_arrays) s
   group by l.indint
), qlines as (
  select concat(
           'select ', a.leadcols, ', ',
           array_to_string(b.srcname, ', '),
           ' from ', 
           tname.t,
           ' where coalesce(',
           array_to_string(b.srcnameonly, ', '),
           ') is not null'
         ) as qline 
    from blowout b
   cross join col_arrays a
   cross join tname
)
select array_to_string(array_agg(qline), ' union all ') as query
  from qlines;
```

Comment: It is fairly big, some of the fields are duplicated over 30 times. With the information_schema.columns, will I be able to match up different fields that are also numbered (such as select serial_number, number3, extra field3 from bad_table) in a dynamic way for all the duplicates, or will I need to specify all the fields for each duplicate?

Comment: @tuskity I put an example in my answer, but it will take some work to build the query the way you want it by correlating like-numbered columns.  I will see if I can do an example of that for you.